# If radio button is selected and select value is selected jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Updating issue: So now i can get the white shirts to work but not yellow. I can switch between small-med-lrg on white, but swapping to yellow still only changes between white shirt sizes. I've condensed code to only show small white and small yellow

```
<select class="color">
   <option value="white">White</option>
   <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
   <input type="radio" class="size" name="size" value="small">Small
   <input type="radio" class="size" name="size" value="medium" checked>Medium
   <input type="radio" class="size" name="size" value="large">Large
```

and js:

```
$('.size').click(function() {
    shirtButtons.hide();
    if( $('.color').val() == 'white' || $('.size:checked').val() == 'small'){ 
        shirtButtons.hide();
        $('.white-small').show();
    }else if( $('.color').val() == 'yellow' || $('.size:checked').val() == 'medium'){ 
        shirtButtons.hide();
        $('.yellow-medium').show();
    }
});
$('.color').change(function() {
    shirtButtons.hide();
    if( $('.color').val() == 'white' || $('.size:checked').val() == 'small'){ 
        shirtButtons.hide();
        $('.white-small').show();
    }else if( $('.color').val() == 'yellow' || $('.size:checked').val() == 'small'){ 
        shirtButtons.hide(); 
        $('.yellow-small').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you forget the js?

Comment: sorry about that! added!

Comment: @Astarkey What is shirtButtons?

Comment: @Pavlo this is a collection of divs i want to show depending on size and color. white-small and yellow-small are both  in shirtButtons. So I hide all, and show what I want.

Comment: @Astarkey Can you show how your collection looks like? Also, take a look on my answer I posted for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some example I have created for you: 
**HTML code**

```
<select class="color">
  <option value="white">White</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>

<input type="radio" class="size" name="size" value="small">Small
<input type="radio" class="size" name="size" value="medium" checked>Medium
<input type="radio" class="size" name="size" value="large">Large
```

**JS code**

```
$('.size').click(function() {
  myFunction();
});

$('select.color').change(function() {
  myFunction();
});

function myFunction(){
  shirtButtons.hide(); // Don't know what is shirtButtons, please explain
  var color = $('select :selected').val();
  var size = $('.size:checked').val();

  if(color  == 'white' || size  == 'small'){ 
    shirtButtons.hide(); // Don't know what is shirtButtons, please explain
    $('.white-small').show();
  } else if( colort == 'yellow' || size == 'medium'){ 
      shirtButtons.hide(); // Don't know what is shirtButtons, please explain
      $('.yellow-medium').show();
    }
}
```

So, you can try to `alert` or `console.log` the variables `color` and `size`. 
Please let me know where you have the problems.

Answer (score 2):

You must add a class `size` to the inputs.

```
 <input type="radio" class="size" name="size" value="small">Small
 <input type="radio" class="size" name="size" value="medium" checked>Medium
 <input type="radio" class="size" name="size" value="large">Large
```

Then use the `:checked` selector to obtain the value:

```
$(".size:checked").val()
```

**Full JS**

```
$('.color, .size').click(function() {
  if( $('.color').val() == 'white' ||  $(".size:checked").val() == 'small'){ 
      shirtButtons.hide();
      $('.white-small').show();
   }else if( $('.color').val() == 'white' ||  $(".size:checked").val() == 'medium'){ 
      shirtButtons.hide();
      $('.white-medium').show();
   } //etc 
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/B93WW/

Comment: I don't think that event click for '.color' select is correct. You should use $('select').change() instead

Comment: @Pavlo Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure `click` is an event on `input`.

Comment: According to the OP's code, he used click event for inputs as well as for the select, but for select this won't work correctly

Comment: Sorry. It will work, but every time you click on select you will always be fired on the click event, even if you don't change anything there, is it clear?

Comment: @KevinBowersox So I updated the code. Adding .change() for the select button. and a .click() for the radio. I'm still having an issue with getting the particular value of yellow select and any size